# Transformation matrix from Cartesian to Schwarzschild

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

The question is really simple: how do I transform a vector from 3D Cartesian $(x, y, z)$ to 3D "space" Schwarzschild $(r, \theta, \phi)$?

I was thinking on using the same transformation matrix as in case of spherical $(r, \theta, \phi)$, but in that case I'll get wrong forms for dot and cross products (and for $\nabla$ operator).

Comment: Isn't this just conceptually wrong? Cartesian space has a different underlying manifold than Schwarzschild space. The question is like finding the coordinate transformation between vectors on a sphere and vectors in a plane. Sure, one can map between the kinds, but the map will necessarily distort them in arbitrary ways.

Comment: Would this belong more on mathematics.se?

Comment: @heather, any way to move the question there, or shall I post it anew?

Comment: @Tajimura if enough people agree with me, it will be migrated automatically. You could also try asking in the [math chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question.  If you pass from $(t,x,y,z)$ to $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$, you obtain $$-dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2).$$  This is the limit as $r\to +\infty$ of the Schwarzschild metric $$-h(r) dt^2 + h(r)^{-1} dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2).$$The horizon function $h$ will act on the $dt^2$ part too, I don't see how can you discuss this without taking the time coordinate into consideration.